# Localize buttons and label in custom tableview cell [swift]

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have a tableview with custom cells.
Each is made of several objects: buttons and texts.
I have some problems localizing the buttons' content.
I have my .strings file with key and translation text defined, for example

```
START="Start";
```

Calling

```
cell.startButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("START", comment: ""), forState: .Normal)
```

Thus instead of having 'Start' as text button I have 'START', why? Of course the text is not localized because I always read 'START'.

EDIT:
I prepared a test app which shows the same behavior.
The download link is [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3017730/provaLocalize.zip)
Someone can help?

EDIT2:
I found the error the string file MUST be called: 'Localizable.strings' I didn't know that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax for strings file is:

```
"id" = "localized message";
```

In your case you have to write:

```
"START" = "Start";
```

whereas you are omitting the double quotes in the identifier:

```
START = "Start"; // This is wrong
```

Side note: if you're doing a lot of localization, I recommend adding this string extension:

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
    }
}
```

then you can make localization much simpler:

```
cell.startButton.setTitle("START".localized, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: Sorry that was just a copy and paste mistake, since I checked if the same problem was in the log and it is. Unfortunately, nothing changes. Thanks for the extension tip, I'll use it, if my localization works....

Comment: Is the string file included in the project?

Comment: @Nicholas See updated answer - maybe I spotted the error

Comment: Yep! I have 'Localization.strings' with START="Start"; in it

Comment: I prepared a test app could you please check that?